# ERROR: Trying to set a surface target that does not exist

Tags: gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I was programming a cool lighting effect on game maker studio 2, it worked, so I decided to make the game fullscreen, however, once I made the game fullscreen an error popped saying:

> Trying to set a surface target that does not exist.

here's the code.

***obj_lighting:***

**Create event:**

```
color = c_ltgray;    
globalvar light;    
light = surface_create(room_width,room_height);    
depth = -999;
```

**Step event:**

```
surface_set_target(light);   
draw_set_color(color);
draw_rectangle(0,0,room_width,room_height,false);
surface_reset_target();
```

**Draw event:**

```
gpu_set_blendmode(bm_subtract);
draw_surface(
    light,
    camera_get_view_x(view_camera[0]),
    camera_get_view_y(view_camera[0])
);
gpu_set_blendmode(bm_normal);
```

***obj_player:***

**End step event:**

```
size = 360;
gpu_set_blendmode(bm_subtract);
surface_set_target(light);
draw_ellipse_color(x-size/2-camera_get_view_x(view_camera[0]),y-size/2-
camera_get_view_y(view_camera[0]),x+size/2-camera_get_view_x(view_camera[0]),y+size/2-camera_get_view_y(view_camera[0]),c_white,c_black,false);
surface_reset_target();
gpu_set_blendmode(bm_normal);
```

***obj_fullscreen:***

**Create event:**

```
window_set_fullscreen(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, **create** events happen before other events, but it is known that sometimes some events might happen beforehand (usually the draw event).

It seems like in your case, your *surface_set_target()* call happens before the **create** event.

You can avoid this by having a condition checking if "light" exists before using the surface.

Comment: That is actually not known, because its not true. Draw events never happen before create events: https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/2_interface/1_editors/events/index.html

The error he is seeing is because the surfaces are volatile.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because surfaces are volatile, as is stated in the docs:

> First, you should realise that surfaces (except the application surface) are "volatile". This means that if the device or window loses focus or is minimised (good examples are when a screensaver comes up in Windows, or on an Android device when the app loses focus due to a call) then the surface may be destroyed. This is because it is stored in the texture memory and may be overwritten when the target platform needs that memory for something else which means that you should always have some type of fail-safe code in place, usually with the surface_exists function.

Docs: https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/drawing/surfaces/index.html

So what you want to do, before *every* time you try to use a surface, is check if it still exists, and if not, create it.

So, put this in the first line of your drawing event:

```
if (!surface_exists(light)) {
    light = surface_create(room_width,room_height);
}
```

this will recreate the surface if it is ever destroyed.

The second fix you should apply, is that the code in your step event is drawing stuff to a surface - while it works, it will slow down your game. Its better to put all drawing related steps in your draw event, so move that step code to the draw event as well (under the surface exists check!)

Then you have another problem: Your obj_player instance is trying to reference the surface created in object "obj_lighting". However, the variable `light` is not known in your `obj_player`, so you will need to reference it: `obj_lighting.light` will do that. Then again, make sure you do the surface checks and preferably do it all in your draw event!